# How to push or pull multi value of array in MongoEngine or pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

Here is a document（name is Word） example:

```
{
"id":"xxxxxxxx",
"words":["hello","world","cat","dog","word1","word2"]
}
```

now I have a word list contains some words, for example:

```
["friend","hello","world","stack","question"]
```

I have 2 operation (Every time I will do one of them, not all of them):
1. PUSH. I want to push all the new word into array, in this case ,the word is "friend","stack","question". "hello" and "world" is already exist, I will not push them in.
2. PULL. I want to pull some word already exist in words, in this case I want to pull  "hello" and "world" out.

One way I know is to do a for loop, but it seems awful. Can I meet what I need in 1 update operation?  such as `collection.update(query,op)`.
I am using flask-MongoEngine and also pymongo operation is also supported.

Comment: The first push would be `$addToSet`, the second one is `$pull`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         words: {
            $setUnion: ["$words", ["friend", "hello", "world", "stack", "question"]]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         words: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$words",
               cond: { $not: { $in: ["$$this", ["hello", "world"]] } }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i31kLVIVfPs)

NB, first adding "hello", "world" and then remove it afterwards looks pointless to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you want to push unique data into array then you can use $addToSet:

let update = await userRepo.getAllNotificationUpdate(
   {$addToSet: {read_by:req.user._id}}
 );
```

if you want to pull  data from array then you can use $pull. please check below 
    url:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/